# Elasticsearch geosearch with distance preference

Tags: elasticsearch

Sorry for the noob question... I have Restaurant objects in Elasticsearch 2.3, each has a GeoPoint and a home delivery distance preference. In pseudocode

```
restaurant: {
  location: (x, y)
  deliveryPreference: 10km
}
```

and a user:

```
user {
  location: (a,b)
}
```

How would I issue a search for a user looking for all restaurants that can deliver in his area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution involves using [`geo_shape`s](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-shape.html). You need to model the restaurant documents as follows:

```
PUT restaurants
{
    "mappings": {
        "restaurant": {
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "location": {
                    "type": "geo_point"
                },
                "delivery_area": {
                    "type": "geo_shape",
                    "tree": "quadtree",
                    "precision": "1m"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can then index your restaurants as follows:

```
POST /restaurants/restaurant/1
{
    "name": "My Food place",
    "location": [-45.0, 45.0],         <-- lon, lat !!!
    "delivery_area": {
        "type": "circle",
        "coordinates" : [-45.0, 45.0], <-- lon, lat !!!
        "radius" : "10km"
    }
}
```

Each restaurant will thus be associated with a circle shape centered on its location and with a proper radius.

Finally, when a user wants to know which restaurant can deliver at the location she is currently at, you can issue the following [`geo_shape` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-shape-query.html):

```
POST /restaurants/_search
{
    "query":{
        "bool": {
            "filter": {
                "geo_shape": {
                    "delivery_area": {
                        "shape": {
                            "type": "point",
                            "coordinates" : [<user_lon>, <user_lat>]
                        },
                        "relation": "contains"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this query, we are retrieving restaurants whose `delivery_area` shape contains the `point` the user is currently located at.

Answer (score 0):

Index the restraunts documents with following mappings

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "type_name": {
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "location": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "location_geo": {
                    "type": "geo_point"
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Use [geo_filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/query-dsl-geo-distance-query.html) query

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": {
                "geo_distance": {
                    "distance": "10km",
                    "location_geo": {
                        "lat": 40,
                        "lon": -70
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The distance is not always 10km, it is dependent on the Restaurant's own preference.